# ActionMailer fail with "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: uriString"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, actionmailer

I'm trying to use ActionMailer 0.7.0 to send a email from my MVC 3 project.

I've followed the sample posted in the project site to the letter.

But when I try to send the email the following error always occurs:

"Value cannot be null. Parameter name: uriString"

It occurs the the @Url.AbsoluteAction in the email body.

```
@using ActionMailer.Net
@model User

@{
    Layout = null;
}

Welcome to My Cool Site, @Model.FirstName

We need you to verify your email.  Click this nifty link to get verified!

// The error happens in the line bellow
@Url.AbsoluteAction("Verify", "Account", new { code = @Model.EmailActivationToken.ToString() })

Thanks!
```

Can some one help me? What am I missing?

Comment: Another issue: I'm still in the development fase, so I configured my mailSettings to "SpecifiedPickupDirectory" as in the example. Even if when I comment the problematic line the email is sent but I also get the exception: "The SMTP host was not specified." Can someone help me with a full example that works without a glitch. Thanks

Comment: If there is no solution can someone suggest another tool to send emails with MVC 3? Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling a few days trying to solve the problem using the code proposed in the sample I gave up.

I've download the source and found out that the problem occurs when your RouteCollection is not standard (which is my case).

So I found an elegant work around that worked for me.

Instead sending the Token to the view and use the Url.AbsoluteAction method I used the Url.Action with the protocol parameter in the controller and sended the complete url in the view model. Like this:

```
new EmailsController().ActivationMail(new ActivationMailViewModel { Email = data.Email, FirstName = data.Name, ActivationLink = Url.Action("VerifyEmail", "Mail", new { code = data.ActivationToken.ToString() }, "http") }).Deliver();
```

The view became:

```
@using ActionMailer.Net
@model User
@{ Layout = null; }
Welcome to My Cool Site, @Model.FirstName

We need you to verify your email.  Click this nifty link to get verified!

@Model.ActivationLink

Thanks!
```

About the SMTP host problem, I found out that in Web.Config even if you set the deliver for "SpecifiedPickupDirectory" you need to add an empty host tag. It's not specified in any ActionMailer sample. Here is the final configuration:

```
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
        <network host="none" />
        <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\temp\" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

I hope it helps someone.

Best luck for everybody.

Answer (score 0):

I've just spent a couple of hours implementing ActionMailer into my MVC project.

I found Scott's screencast really helped me.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QQRzYo7k9Vs&hd=1

It explains how to get round the SMTP host issue, as well as how to set up the User models etc.

I'm still getting stuck on user email verification and will try to let you know if I sort it out.

However, you don't need this to send 'ordinary' emails. So my advice would be to leave it out for now until you can get the emails working OK.

Hope that helps, and I'll be back to you when I sort out email verification!

Cheers

Chewie